# Deploying Vue 3 App to subdomain of shared hosting (SiteGround)

Tags: deployment, vuejs3, shared-hosting

I am trying to deploy my Vue 3 app on a subdomain of a shared hosting plan.
The main domain hosts a Wordpress Website.
I am adding the .htaccess file to the public_html folder of the subdomain.

It works fine, but when I reload a page I get a 404 response.

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
  Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Are you using Vue Router?

Comment: Yes, I am using Vue router and vuex store.